# How should I balance my logo icon and logotype when one is above the other?

Tags: logo, icon, scale, composition, balance

I tried searching through Google and YouTube for "how to balance your logo" but all I got was tips on balancing icon and text when icon is sitting exactly next to the text.

But what if the icon is on top of the text? How big the icon should be? How much spacing should there be in between the icon and the logo text? What if there's a tagline underneath?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you show us an example of your logo and text, or what problem you are experiencing?  Balance is generally a subjective choice. There are no rules as such, and much would depend on the specific layout, and  logo itself.  It's really hard to answer a question like this without a visual example.